# How to output a tibble with if_else, and how to output a list-column with mutate?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidy

I'm attempting to extrapolate missing values from a time series. I'm comfortable with tidyverse, but seem to be running into a bit of a roadblock and am not sure if I should be taking a different approach.

I have a data-frame with unevenly spaced-in-time measurements. If the time between measurements exceeds a certain threshold, I'd like to do a linear extrapolation between the nearest time above and below, with the measured values being evenly spaced. Something like:

```
df <- tibble(
  time = c(1, 2, 3, 8, 9), 
  meas = c(200, 300, 320, 500, 600)
);

avg_meas_interval <- median(df$time - lag(df$time);

df %>% mutate(
  if_else(
    time - lag(time) > threshold,
    tibble(
      time_extrp = seq(lag(time), time, avg_meas_interval),
      meas_extrp = seq(lag(meas), meas, length.out = length(time_extrp))
    ),
    NA
  )
)
```

I would then have a column of tibbles that represent the extrapolated rows that should be inserted before a given row, or NA if there's no rows to be inserted. I could pull this and row_bind.

Now, there's a few issues I've been bumping into with this approach:

1. if_else doesn't like returning tibbles, as it wants the possible outcomes of the if-else to have equal length.
2. Mutate doesn't like outputting lists of tibbles. I can get around this with just using map, outputting a separate list to a new variable (so that it's not part of the tibble), and then rowbinding, but this seems a bit circuitous.

It seems a simple extrapolation like this, where the output size is dependent on the input data, is extremely hard to implement in pure functional style. Not sure if there's a better approach than just implementing this in procedural R or python.

Comment: `if_else` is for vectors, nothing more complex. FYI, `avg_meas_interval` is incomplete, missing a close-paren; fixing that, and it's now `NA`, seemingly not useful. If you want to embed a frame inside a column, it needs to be _nested_ as a _list-column_, often done with `lapply` or similar list-generator. (Perhaps `avg_meas_interval <- median(df$time) - lag(df$time)`? It is a vector with non-`NA` values.)

Comment: I understand you say that you want a list-column where the contents are rows that should be inserted before the current row. Are you intent on leaving it like this, or do you intend to subsequently combine them in so that you have one contiguous frame?

Comment: Thanks, yes I intend to insert them so I have one contiguous frame. Switching from if_else to if inside a map function seems to be the key here, thanks for this r2evans. To actually insert the rows, would you suggest using pull() and bind_rows()?

Comment: Something like `df %>% bind_rows(df %>% pull(extrp)) %>% select(-extrp)`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this?

```r
threshold <- 3
df %>%
  mutate(
    across(c(time, meas), lag, .names = "lag_{.col}"),
    intrvl = c(1, rep(median(diff(time)), n() - 1)), # I'm inferring here ...
    extrp = purrr::pmap(
      list(time, lag_time, meas, lag_meas, intrvl),
      ~ if (!is.na(..2) && (..1 - ..2) > threshold) {
         tibble(time_extrp = seq(..2, ..1, length.out=..5),
                meas_extrp = seq(..4, ..3, length.out=..5))
      })
  )
# # A tibble: 5 × 6
#    time  meas lag_time lag_meas intrvl extrp           
#   <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl> <list>          
# 1     1   200       NA       NA      1 <NULL>          
# 2     2   300        1      200      1 <NULL>          
# 3     3   320        2      300      1 <NULL>          
# 4     8   500        3      320      1 <tibble [1 × 2]>
# 5     9   600        8      500      1 <NULL>
```

Note that the `seq` calls need to return the same length, ergo `length.out=` here. In your original call, using the interval by itself would produce `time_extrp` on the order of a few elements, and `meas_extrp` on the order of 100s of elements. In its current form, this produces a 1-row tibble to be inserted, I suggest you might prefer something more akin to this:

```r
    extrp = purrr::pmap(
      list(time, lag_time, meas, lag_meas),
      ~ if (!is.na(..2) && (..1 - ..2) > threshold) {
         len <- ceiling((..1 - ..2) / threshold)
         tibble(time_extrp = seq(..2, ..1, length.out=len),
                meas_extrp = seq(..4, ..3, length.out=len))
      })
```

(inside the call to `mutate`).

---

An alternative, since you say you're going to join it back in anyway:

```r
threshold <- 3
intrvl <- 2 # use something meaningful
df %>%
  mutate(nexttime = lead(time)) %>%
  filter(nexttime - time > threshold) %>%
  reframe(time = unlist(Map(seq, time, nexttime, by=intrvl))) %>%
  full_join(df, by = "time") %>%
  arrange(time) %>%
  mutate(meas2 = if_else(is.na(meas), approx(time, meas, xout = time)$y, meas))
# # A tibble: 7 × 3
#    time  meas meas2
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1   200   200
# 2     2   300   300
# 3     3   320   320
# 4     5    NA   392
# 5     7    NA   464
# 6     8   500   500
# 7     9   600   600
```

I created `meas2` in order to compare the original `meas` side-by-side with the `NA`-interpolated values, feel free to overwrite `meas`. Also, there are certainly other tools available for `NA`-interpolation, this is one way, others exist (e.g., `zoo::na.approx`).

The first thing we do here is determine where the gaps exist (`mutate(..) %>% filter(..)`), then generate the needed `time`s (`reframe`, from `dplyr_1.1.0` or later), and join them back in with the original data (`full_join`). It can be insightful to see this stepwise:

```r
df %>%
  mutate(nexttime = lead(time)) %>%
  filter(nexttime - time > threshold)
# # A tibble: 1 × 3
#    time  meas nexttime
#   <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1     3   320        8

... %>%
  reframe(time = unlist(Map(seq, time, nexttime, by=intrvl)))
# # A tibble: 3 × 1
#    time
#   <dbl>
# 1     3
# 2     5
# 3     7

... %>%
  full_join(df, by = "time")
# # A tibble: 7 × 2
#    time  meas
#   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     3   320
# 2     5    NA
# 3     7    NA
# 4     1   200
# 5     2   300
# 6     8   500
# 7     9   600
```

From there, we just `arrange` the data and interpolate the missing values.

Comment: See my edit @Dragonsheep, one-step combined with the data, on `pull` required.